# The effect about empty string in NFA

Tags: finite-automata

I am learning Sipser's book "Introduction to the Theory of Computation" on automata theory. I am confused about the effect about empty string in NFA when reading the first chapter

There is a state diagram of nondeterministic finite automaton N1
[image: Nondeterministic finite automaton N1]

If we feed string "010110" into N1
Then as showed in the book, the computation process will be

[image: The computation of N1 on input 010110]

I can't get understand that when N1 read the second symbol from string,that is "1", the state "q1" should split into "q1" and "q2". Why there exist also "q3"

The principle of computation involving "empty string" is described as 
"If a state with an symbol on some exiting arrow is encountered, the machine split into multiple copies without reading any input"

Comment: Where did you get the second picture

Comment: It is a screenshot from a pdf edition for that book. Is there something wrong with the second picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reach $q_3$ from $q_1$ by reading $1$ followed by $\varepsilon$ as follows $q_1 \xrightarrow{1} q_2 \xrightarrow{\varepsilon} q_3$.